# Bones displayed as sticks in edit mode don't appear selected

Tags: 3d-view, edit-mode, bones

This might be a silly one but for the life of me I couldn't find an answer while googling. I'm doing a rigging tutorial and the author changes his bones to be displayed as sticks and they look pretty clear, but after I do it, they're all black and in edit mode I can't tell if I selected the bone or not  any idea on what's going on? The tutorial guy is using 2.8 and I'm on 3.6 but the default stick display can't be that hard to read can it?

[image]

Comment: It should appear yellow when selected, could you please share the armature so that we can test?

Comment: Are there overlapping bones?

Comment: There are no overlapping bones. Here's my file: https://we.tl/t-BP3AwzodDs BTW the same thing happens when I create a single bone in a new file. Maybe a bug?

Comment: I've updated Blender, created a new file, added a single bone and that's how it looks selected with stick display in edit mode. https://ibb.co/XVpc8yn It's like it's selected but there's some noise on it? I'm lost.

Comment: Ok I think it's a bug. This is exactly what happens in my case: https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/108575

Comment: I can select the bones in the file you share, so I'm not sure what's happening for you